# Android: actionbarsherlock + maven + Intellij create apk

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

This is my project structure in intellij:

[image]

and this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>P....</groupId>
    <artifactId>P...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>P...</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-webdav</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is what i run for create an apk from my project:

[image]

everything is ok when i run my program inside emulator using intellij but when i try to create an apk, this error is shown from maven:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building P... 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:apk (default-cli) @ P.... ---
[INFO] Copying local assets files to combined assets directory.
[INFO] Enabling debug build for apk.
[INFO] C:\Users\...\android-sdk\build-tools\18.1.0\aapt.exe [package, -f, -M, D:\Projects\P....\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, D:\Projects\P....\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, D:\Projects\P...\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets, -I, C:\Users\...\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar, -F, D:\Projects\P....\target\P....-1.0.ap_, --debug-mode]
[INFO] D:\Projects\P....\res\values\styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.118s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 14 11:23:35 IRST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/13M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:apk (default-cli) on project P....: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\...\android-sdk\build-tools\18.1.0\aapt.exe package -f -M D:\Projects\P...\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\Projects\P....\res --auto-add-overlay -A D:\Projects\P...\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets -I C:\Users\...\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar -F D:\Projects\P....\target\P...-1.0.ap_ --debug-mode", Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

what is wrong in my settings???

**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.................."
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".authentication.AuthenticateActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.DisplayInfoActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.Preferences"/>
        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.ParentActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and there is no theme.
This is styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <style name="Animations" />
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
    <style name="OAuthDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>

    <color name="setup_text_hint">#777777</color>
    <color name="setup_text_typed">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: 1. why packaging is jar and no apk?
2. why you have imported the sherlock bar module since you have declared the dependency - and probably you use the local repository

Comment: 1. because of an error packaging must be jar. when i set it to apk another compile time error happens. 2. this is the instruction of using actionbarsherlock. because it has some resource files that needs to import project source and declare as dependency.

Comment: I said that everything is ok in emulator and project runs fine but i can not create apk!

Comment: First the packaging should be apk in order com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 works as expected
Second there is not instruction to use both maven dependency & module you need to choose between two. I have already used Sherlock many times with only the maven dependency - without module import and everything works fine. Try to change the packaging to apk, remove Sherlock module - keep only the maven dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an working example maven-intellij-sherlock:

[image]

And the pom.xml is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>.................</groupId>
    <artifactId>..........-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>..........-android</artifactId>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<name>.............| Android apk</name>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

edit:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>lint</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>lint</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>true</release>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>${android.api.version}</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <lint>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                        </lint>
                        <proguard>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <jvmArguments>
                                <jvmArgument>-Xms1G</jvmArgument>
                                <jvmArgument>-Xmx2G</jvmArgument>
                            </jvmArguments>
                        </proguard>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: try the com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 plugin without version:

check **edit**

Comment: and again: D:\Projects\...\res\values\styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: So you have removed the module?

Comment: could you please post the AndroidManifest.xml and themes.xml (if any)?

Comment: Also post the **@style/AppTheme** configuration

Comment: Try to re-import maven projects. Then if you open the 'project structure' you should see also the ~apklib-com.actionbarsherlock_actionsherlock_x.x.x project

Comment: I can already see that project. And  i'm able to test project in emulator. This error happens in apk creation proccess.

Comment: if you build from command line 'maven package' the problem still exists?

Comment: apk generation is ok when i use the "mvn package" command but created apk file can not install on phone because of an unknown error.

Comment: After running the mvn package command in cmd, now intellij is working without any problem. Problem solved and created apk installed successfuly on my phone. Thank you so much.